# How to run a Synthetic Control Method in R on Mac?

Tags: r, versioning, r-package

I'm currently trying to run a SCM using R (4.3) on my Mac (Intel chip, 12.1 Monterey). I only found the package Synth to do so. However it seems that I can't install it on R 4.3.1 or 4.3.2 for Mac.

I tried to use the previous version of R, which is 4.2, since the package is supposed to be relatively new i thought it was gonna work but it didn't. I'm wondering if it's a problem coming from R Studio (i'm using 2023.03)

Comment: These versions of R are over 5 years old, and most package developers have moved on to newer versions of R. Any reason you can't update?

Comment: If for some reason you can't (or aren't allowed to) update to R 4.2.x, you're probably stuck downloading the source for `Synth` and building it on your machine.  And no guarantees that will work.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I tried with R 4.3 and 4.2 and it didn't worked either. However i found another more recent package called "MSCMT" which worked perfectly